# Pointer subtraction on void elements

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

EDITED: Basically, I am trying to determine in a vector, being given one element, what the next element is. The elements are contiguous. The expression below is supposed to pass the first element as the previous element, and it should return a pointer to the second element. I want the distance to return the difference b/w the previous pointer and the first pointer to find where the second element is...

I have this expression:

```
int next = *(char *)v_next(vec, vec_first(vec));
```

Then in the function being called, I have this line in order to determine the position of one pointer from another..

```
void *v_next(const vector *vec, const void *previous) {
    ...
    void *first = cvec_first(cv);
    int distance = (char*) &previous - (char*) &first;
```

However, when I compare the first element and the second element, it returns a distance of 32. If I divide this distance by char*'s size, I get 8. That's clearly way too many bytes to separate one pointer from another and therefore this expression doesn't work out to find the right position...

```
    next = (char*) vec->elems + vec->elemsz + distance;
```

How can I get the subtraction working properly?

Comment: You need to clarify `previous` and `first`. They're only mentioned once.

Comment: @marchon There is nothing clear what you are trying to achieve. Value 32 says nothing for us. We can not answer whether it is a valid distance or not.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I've edited it with more information.

Comment: Wouldn't `(char*)previous + vec->elemsz` suffice to give you the right pointer?

Comment: I've tried that, but when I use the expression beginning with "int next" above, it only prints 0.

Comment: Have a look at section 5.3 & 5.4 of K&R.  It will explain the problems that you are getting.

Comment: It would be great to see the vector structure. That would probably help considerably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that you need to substract pointers of proper "undecayed" type (whatever it is in your case). See following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, *p, *q;

    p = a;
    q = a + 1;

    printf("Corect distance: %d\n", (int) (q - p));
    printf("Incorrect distance: %d\n", (int) ((char *)q - (char *)p));

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `p` and `q` have to point into the same array, or more precisely (C99 6.5.6 Additive operators):

> [...] to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of
>   the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements.

otherwise it's UB. The result of substaction has implementation-defined type `ptrdiff_t` (that's why I casted result to `int`).

Comment: I'm trying to keep the pointers generic type - void - so that the subtraction can be done with any type.

Comment: Untrue, `void *` definitely does not represent correct size of array elements. In other words you need specifically pointer that points to object of the same type as array element. Casting to `(char*)` you are saying something like "I am sure that my array has elements o type `char`".

Comment: @marchon: Impossible.  Tell me; how many bytes should the expression `some_vp - N` subtract from `some_vp`?  You can't know because you have lost all of your type information.  For this same reason you cannot dereference a `void*`. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the wrong pointers. `&first` is the location of the variable first, which is a local variable. Same for `&previous`. So you're comparing two pointers that has nothing to do with what's in the vector.

From your third statement it looks like you want the offset in bytes. You shouldn't divide it by anything if so. It's given by:

```
int distance = (char*)previous - (char*)first;
```

(note that you might want to use `ptrdiff_t` instead of `int` depending on your architecture.)

Your statement for next should then work, but it should also be the same as:

```
next = (char*)previous + vec->elemsz;
```

> I've tried that, but when I use the expression beginning with "int next" above, it only prints 0.

That's because of your first line, where you're only reading a single byte (`char`):

```
int next = *(char *)v_next(vec, vec_first(vec));
           ^^^^^^^^^
```

You're casting to the wrong type here. You want to cast to the type that's stored in the vector, which I'm guessing is `int`. So it should read:

```
int next = *(int *)v_next(vec, vec_first(vec));
```